# How to create imageviews dynamically?

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, android-imageview

[image]

Hello everyone. I need to create something like this,displayed in a picture. I have no idea how should I implement it?.
If I press camera button and add photo - it must be added to that list.

I think to create a row of invisible ImageView and initialize them when it needed, but I think it is bad solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this way to create the imageviews dynamically:

```
ImageView iv=new ImageView(context);
        iv.setId(id);
        iv.layout(l, t, r, b);
```

l,t,r and b specify the padding from left,top,right and bottom respectively 
then you can add this imageview to your respective layout

Answer (score 0):

There is lots of ways to do. Use first portion as ListView and second portion as customized GridView if any data changes update both listview and gridview adapter.

Comment: but how to add delete button on it? Maybe it is a spessial library to make this?

Comment: you can design a customized GridView, for example <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/baselayer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"> inflat it in GirdView adapter

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
        </ImageView>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/closeButton"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
        </Button>
    </RelativeLayout>

Answer (score 0):

Use this after image get captured

```
    //LinearLayOut Setup
        LinearLayout linearLayout= new LinearLayout(this);
        linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

        //ImageView Setup
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
        //setting image resource
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
        //setting image position
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        //adding view to layout
        linearLayout.addView(imageView);
        //make visible to program
        setContentView(linearLayout);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add views dynamically that you defined default values in xml for using an inflater.  The "parent" in the code below  should be a ViewGroup like a Linear or RelativeLayout, or even a GridLayout.

You can probably use a LinearLayout with horizontal orientation to get the effect you are looking for.

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    final ImageView iv = (ImageView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.imageview_thumb, parent, false);

    //Zero means its in the back;
    parent.addView(iv, 0);
```

Layout Code:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/imageview_fc"
    android:layout_width="142dp"
    android:layout_height="142dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

create a gallery to show the image horizontally. when you capture image, write it to a folder and read all files from that folder. each time when you capture image you need to refresh gallery data. if you want a image with cross button then create a separate xml file like below

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:background="#FF8825">


<ImageView 
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FF2225"/>

<ImageButton 
    android:id="@+id/crossButton"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_gravity="top|right"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/btn_dialog_normal"/>
```

and inflate it for each gallery item